# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error in c++, header apparently isn't linked

Tags: c++

Hi I'm having some problems with c++, when I try to compile my 3 files, main.cpp, My_Stack.cpp and My_Stack.hpp I get the "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" error, as if I hadn't included the header file and if I add "#include "My_Stack.cpp"" instead of "#include "My_Steak.hpp"" in main.cpp it works fine.

---

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "My_Stack.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    My_Stack<int> s = My_Stack<int>();
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    cout << s.pop() << endl;
    cout << s.pop() << endl;


}
```

---

```
//My_Stack.hpp
#ifndef My_Stack_hpp
#define My_Stack_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class My_Stack {

public:
    My_Stack();
    void push(T v);
    T pop();

private:
    class My_Stack_Node {
    public:
        T data;
        My_Stack_Node* next;
        My_Stack_Node(T n) {
            data = n;
            next = NULL;
        }
    };
    My_Stack_Node* head;

};


#endif /* My_Stack_hpp */
```

---

```
//My_Stack.cpp
#include "My_Stack.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
My_Stack<T>::My_Stack() {
    this->head = NULL;
}

template<class T>
void My_Stack<T>::push(T v) {
    if (this->head == NULL) {
        this->head = new My_Stack_Node(v);
    }
    else {
        My_Stack_Node* aux = new My_Stack_Node(v);
        aux->next = this->head;
        this->head = aux;
    }
}

template<class T>
T My_Stack<T>::pop() {
    My_Stack_Node* aux = this->head;
    this->head = this->head->next;
    return aux->data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Template definitions must go inside corresponding header file i.e  definitions in My_Stack.cpp must be put inside My_Stack.hpp.

Recommend you to go over the faq:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl

Pasting the relevant part from the faq:

> A template is not a class or a function. A template is a “pattern”
>   that the compiler uses to generate a family of classes or
>   functions.
>  In order for the compiler to generate the code,
>   it must see both the template definition (not just declaration) and
>   the specific types/whatever used to “fill in” the template. For
>   example, if you’re trying to use a Foo, the compiler must see
>   both the Foo template and the fact that you’re trying to make a
>   specific Foo.
>  Your compiler probably doesn’t remember
>   the details of one .cpp file while it is compiling another .cpp file.
>   It could, but most do not and if you are reading this FAQ, it almost
>   definitely does not. BTW this is called the “separate compilation
>   model.”